# Detect tablet or phone, multi screen view problem

Tags: java, android

To recognize whether I am dealing with a phone or a tablet, I use the function of checking screen width and height and converting to inches .... Below I present this function. Everything works, but when the user on the tablet opens two applications in the multi screen view (split screen) then the measurement of inches is different and it detects me as a phone ... How to prevent it

```
public boolean isTablet() {
        try {
            // Compute screen size

            DisplayMetrics dm =
                    context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            float screenWidth = dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi;
            float screenHeight = dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi;
            double size = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(screenWidth, 2) +
                    Math.pow(screenHeight, 2));
            // Tablet devices have a screen size greater than  inches

            return size >= 7.0;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your app will be in a window that is smaller than the screen in split-screen (all Android 8.0+ devices) and free-form multi-window (Chrome OS, Samsung DeX, Windows 11, etc.). On Android 12L and higher tablets, split-screen is going to be the norm. So, you need to consider revising your approach to not worry about phones versus tablets.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for reply. How, then, is it possible to definitively detect whether I am dealing with a tablet or a phone?

Comment: "Phone" and "tablet" are marketing labels and have little meaning in programming. Your definition of "tablet" (something with a screen size of 7.0" or higher) and somebody else's definition of "tablet" (something without voice telephony capability) can be very different. My point is: stop thinking in terms of phones and tablets. Instead, focus in specific technical differences that matter.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay. I have two layouts that I want to display depending on the screen size, unfortunately the matter is complicated when the user runs two app (multi screen). So how do I know if I am dealing with a small screen or over 7.0 "?

Comment: "I have two layouts that I want to display depending on the screen size" -- the screen size is irrelevant. The window size is what is relevant. In the very simple case, the window size resembles the screen size. Split-screen, freeform multi-window, foldables, etc. are cases where the window size is substantially different from the screen size. So, why are you worried about the screen size? Would you care about the screen size, rather than the window size, in a desktop OS or in a Web app?

Comment: Typically, we use resource sets for handling different window sizes. So, in `res/layout/foo.xml` you have a smaller version of your UI and in `res/layout-w640dp/foo.xml` you have a larger version of your UI (one suitable for windows where the current width is 640dp or wider). You just ask Android to load `R.layout.foo`, and it chooses the right version based on the window size.